# "AutoBean has frozen" exception on GWT app with Objectify

Tags: gwt, google-cloud-datastore, requestfactory, objectify

My GWT app includes persistence through RequestFactory + Objectify (GAE Datastore). Code below works (data is successfully stored in GAE), but exception below occurs. Any ideas? Thanks

```
10:22:56.772 [ERROR] [dialective] Uncaught exception escaped

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The AutoBean has been frozen
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.checkFrozen(AbstractAutoBean.java:195)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.setProperty(AbstractAutoBean.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.ClientPropertyContext$Setter$.call$(ClientPropertyContext.java)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.ClientPropertyContext.set(ClientPropertyContext.java:137)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$3.visitValueProperty(AbstractRequestContext.java:910)
    at com.gw.dialective.shared.model.DiagramProxyAutoBean_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_EntityProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_ValueProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_BaseProxyCategory.traverseProperties(DiagramProxyAutoBean_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_EntityProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_ValueProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_BaseProxyCategory.java:222)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.traverse(AbstractAutoBean.java:166)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.accept(AbstractAutoBean.java:101)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.processReturnOperation(AbstractRequestContext.java:879)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.processReturnOperations(AbstractRequestContext.java:1215)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.access$7(AbstractRequestContext.java:1185)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$StandardPayloadDialect.processPayload(AbstractRequestContext.java:347)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$5.onTransportSuccess(AbstractRequestContext.java:1108)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.client.DefaultRequestTransport$1.onResponseReceived(DefaultRequestTransport.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**MyApp.java**

```
public void update(int index, DiagramBox object, String value) {                            
            object.setDescription(value);
            sendUpdateDiagramBoxEvent(index, BasicConstants.editableTableFields.DESCRIPTION, value); // send event to the View
            DiagramRequest diagramRequest = requestFactory.diagramRequest();
            DiagramProxy newDiagramProxy = diagramRequest.create(DiagramProxy.class); // Create new diagram entity
            Date date = new Date();
            newDiagramProxy.set_id("DUEN39AS89AS");
            newDiagramProxy.setDateCreated(date);
            newDiagramProxy.setDateEdited(date);
            diagramRequest.saveAndReturn(newDiagramProxy).fire(); 
          }
        });
```

**DiagramRequest.java**

```
@Service(value=DiagramDao.class, locator=DaoServiceLocator.class)
public interface DiagramRequest extends RequestContext {
    Request<DiagramProxy> saveAndReturn(DiagramProxy diagram);
}
```

**DiagramDao.java**

```
public class DiagramDao extends ObjectifyDao<Diagram>{

    public Diagram saveAndReturn(Diagram diagram)
    {
        Key<Diagram> key = this.put(diagram);
        try
        {
            return this.get(key);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**DaoServiceLocator.java**

```
public class DaoServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {
    public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
        try {
            return clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if the server returns the same entity as has been received (sent by the client) but as a distinct instance.

In your case, in `saveAndReturn`, if `this.get(key)` returns a different object than the one received as argument, then you'll have that issue. You'd better `return diagram` here.

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7341